# AsterixDB unable to import datetime when importing from CSV file (SQL)

Tags: sql, csv, asterixdb

I am attempting to load a database from a CSV file using AsterixDB. Currently, it works using only string, int, and double fields. However, I have a column in the CSV file that is in DateTime format. Currently I am importing them as strings, which works fine, but I would like to import them as the SQL DateTime data type. When I try changing my schema and reimporting I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Code: 1 "org.apache.hyracks.algebricks.common.exceptions.NotImplementedException: No value parser factory for fields of type datetime"
```

All entries are in this format `02/20/2010 12:00:00 AM`.
I know this isn't exactly inline with the format specified by the [Asterix Data Model](https://nightlies.apache.org/asterixdb/datamodel.html#PrimitiveTypesDateTime), however, I tried a test line with the proper format and the error persisted.

Does this mean AsterixDB cant parse DateTime when doing mass imports? And if so how can I get around this issue?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't you report this to the developers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, after discussing with some colleagues, we believe that AsterixDB does not currently support DateTime parsing when mass importing. Our solution was to upsert every entry in the dataset with the parsing built into the query.

We used the following query:

```
upsert into csv_set (
  SELECT parse_datetime(c.Date_Rptd, "M/D/Y h:m:s a") as Datetime_Rptd,
  parse_datetime(c.Date_OCC, "M/D/Y h:m:s a") as Datetime_OCC,
  c.*
  FROM csv_set c
);
```

As you can see we parse the strings using the parse_datetime function from the [AsterixDB Temporal Functions](https://asterixdb.apache.org/docs/0.8.8-incubating/aql/functions.html#TemporalFunctions) library. This query intentionally doesn't erase the column with the DateTimes in string format, although that would be very simple to do if your application requires it. If anyone has a better or more elegant solution please feel free to add to this thread!